# Data Warehouse attribute that describes its timeframe?

Tags: data-warehouse, etl, business-intelligence, terminology

I am writing a document about a Data Warehouse system, and would like to know if is there a single word (noun) that describes the DW attribute of how many time it contains?

I mean, if a DW contains 5 years, I want a noun for it, for instance: the XXX of DW is 5 years.

Likewise we call how fresh the data is as its Latency, and how often the data is updated as Periodicity.

Comment: I read on a blog that the term is Retention, or Retention Period.

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/thomase/archive/2014/08/21/change-the-data-warehouse-retention-period.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I would go with "the date range encompassed by the data warehouse is x."

This eliminates all possible confusion about the intent by deliberately using words that are understandable by non-technical people.

Answer (score 1):

Retention Period, as suggested by Thiago Anitelle, would be accurate if you are trying to say that you *keep data for X amount of time*. This would work in a scenario where you load data today, 9/25/2015, from a source system that has data for the year of 1980 starting at 1/1/1980.

With a retention period of 5 years we indicate that the data loaded today, from 1980, will stay in our system until 9/25/2020 at which point it will be deleted from the DW.

Using the same data load example: If you are trying to state *the earliest date of data* in your warehouse is from 1/1/1980 then why not just say that? A plain English sentence is often times worth a million acronyms or buzz words.

**The Earliest date of data in the data warehouse is January 1st, 1980.**

I have not heard of a specific term for this before, and even if you manage to find one, I still recommend you stick to the basic, yet proven, sentence.

Answer (score 1):

***Scope*** is another possibility to describe this concept.

I.e:

The ***scope*** of the data warehouse is the past 5 years.